# Count rows to end

Tags: mysql

```
 id      date     group n1  n2  n3  n4  n5
18853   1945-01-05  BA  87  34  1   59  50
18854   1945-01-13  BA  6   66  1   16  48 <= the last 16, 7 rows to the end
18855   1945-01-20  BA  38  14  24  78  36
18856   1945-01-27  BA  49  30  87  15  65 <= the last 49, 5 rows to the end
18857   1945-02-03  BA  30  64  36  5   32
18858   1945-02-10  BA  15  36  37  86  31 <= the last 36, 3 rows to the end
18859   1945-02-17  BA  86  78  69  7   60 <= the last 86, 2 rows to the end
18860   1945-02-24  BA  83  7   72  88  19 <= the last 7, 1 row to the end
18861   1945-03-03  BA  47  20  77  73  30 <= the last 47, 0 rows to the end
```

I have the above table (it's ordered by id, however I plan to order it by date). Is there a way to get the number of rows between a specified number and the last row in mySql?
Note that some numbers are repeated twice or more times. The script should use the lowest rows.
Here is the table that mySQL should output:

```
Number|Rows count to the end
16|7
7|1
86|2
49|5
47|0
36|3
```

The query should search columns n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 and pick the value most nearly to the end and count the remaining rows to the end.
Thanks ;)

Comment: @hims056 I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to count the rows to the end. That's my problem.

Comment: Some questions:  First, presumably your first column defines the order of the rows. Is that correct?  Second, why is "7" one row to the end in your example? It appears both in row 18859 and 18860. (I guess you want the latest occurrence of the number. But this needs to be stated.) Third, what are you trying to do?

Comment: 16 is in the second row. If you count from the 2nd row to the last row, there are 7 rows.

Comment: Rows are ordered by date

Comment: I'm trying to list the numbers of rows to the end for each number that appears in the table.
E.g.: 1=2 rows to the end; 2=10 rows to the end; 3=64 rows to the end; etc.

Comment: i dont get your last example in the comments. please elaborate.

Comment: I've edited the question. I think now you can understand better

Comment: does one of your 5 rows with numbers in it contain all numbers that are available in all 5 of those rows?

Comment: I've edited the question once again to let you better understand

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your unnamed columns are named as follows:

```
c1      c2          c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8
18853   1945-01-05  BA  87  34  1   59  50
18854   1945-01-13  BA  6   66  1   16  48
18855   1945-01-20  BA  38  14  24  78  36
18856   1945-01-27  BA  49  30  87  15  65
18857   1945-02-03  BA  30  64  36  5   32
18858   1945-02-10  BA  15  36  37  86  31
18859   1945-02-17  BA  86  78  69  7   60
18860   1945-02-24  BA  83  7   72  88  19
18861   1945-03-03  BA  47  20  77  73  30
```

Furthermore assuming c1 is you PK index column and column c7 is the one you're interested in, following might give you what you want:

```
select t1.c7, MAX(t1.c1), (select count(*)
              from table t2
              where MAX(t1.c1) < t2.c1) as rowsToEnd
from table t1
group by t1.c7
```

Ok, after having supposedly understood what you want, the following should give you what you want:

**EDIT:** After having read Imre L's answer i realized i totally forgot about the IN operator, so this is the more elegant solution:

**EDIT AGAIN:** After having read your question update.
This is assuming that one of c4, c5, c6, c7, c8 contains all numbers that are occur in any one of those rows:

```
select distinct t3.c4, ( select count(*) AS RowsToEnd
                         from table t1
                         where t1.c1 > ( select max(t2.c1)
                                         from table t2
                                         where t3.c4 IN 
                                         (t2.c4, t2.c5, t2.c6, t2.c7, t2.c8)
                        )
from table t3
```

Comment: 1) What is table t2? Should I create another table in the database?
2) It's possible to extend this query to the c3,c4,c5,c6,c8 too?

Comment: 1) i just assumed your tables name is "table". t1 and t2 are just table aliases, since i'm querying the table 2-times (without aliases that wouldn't be possible since the dbms would not be able to determine to which query i'm refering to).
2) well that would be a pretty bloated query... 
there is probably are better way to achieve your goal which will make changes in your model necessary, but for a quick and dirty (very dirty) solution you could just copy this query and replace c7 with whichever column you want.

Comment: I want that query should consider all c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8 columns in the same time. For example, if I want to know the rows to the end for 7, your query shows 2. But it should show 1 because there's a 7 in column c5

Comment: ah, now i understand, i thought you meant the same number could occur multiple times within a column, not in 5 different columns... well that complicates things a bit..
so is the following correct: you have one number as a parameter (e.g. "7") and you search c4, c5, c6 and c7 for that number. Then you want to know the distance to the end for the occurance with the highest value in c1/c2?

Comment: Yes!! You've understood everything

Answer (score 0):

assuming the columns of numbers are names n1..n6

using 16 as the example number

```
select count(1) 
  from tablename 
 where date > (select date 
               from tablename 
              where 16 in (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6) 
              order by date desc
              limit 1)
```

what about reoccuring dates?